# Change poster image with jQuery

Tags: video.js

Is there any way to chage the poster image dinamically?

I tried like this:

jQuery('#example_video_1').attr('poster', 'http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.jpg');

but not working.
I need because im changing myPlayer.src, so i need to change also poster image, in my video gallery.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works.

```
$("#example_video_1 .vjs-poster").css('background-image', 'url(http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.jpg)').show();
```